# Adding GDI shapes on BITMAP in MFC

Tags: bitmap, mfc, gdi

I have loaded a bitmap image and managed to draw an ellipse over the bitmap image. The problem is the ellipse appears to be as if it was drawn with a brush, but I have used the pen to draw the ellipse. (i.e.) The ellipse is opaque. I want it to be transparent. Also the color of the ellipse is fixed as white. Its not changing even when I change the RGB values.

Here is the code

```
void CImagePreview1View::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CBitmap bmp;
    CDC MemDC;
    bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_FOOD);
    MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    CBitmap *bmpPrevious=MemDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    dc.BitBlt(20,30,436,364,&MemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    dc.SelectObject(bmpPrevious);
    CPen newPen;
    newPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(152,125,175));
    dc.SelectObject(newPen);
    dc.Ellipse(30,60,130,160);
}
```

Comment: The SelectObject method returns a handle to the previous object.  Try selecting the original object back into the dc.  It should act like a "file close".  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for info.

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected transparent brush:

```
  CBrush brush;
  brush.CreateStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
  CBrush* oldBrush =  (CBrush*)MemDC.SelectObject(&brush);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have used pen. Isn't a pen supposed to draw hollow shapes?

Comment: Both pen and brush are used to draw shapes. So you have to select brush also.

Comment: As far as I know Pen draws a hollow ellipse and brush draws filled ellipse. My question is Y did I end up getting filled ellipse even though I have used pen?

Comment: Yes, you'll end up getting filled ellipse even if you have used only pen. The problem is that the default brush will be used in this case. So you'll have to select NULL_BRUSH in order to draw transparent shape.